# Add values on subsequent call in javascript function.?

Tags: javascript

Let's consider I have the following function call,

```
function add(){
    x = 0 ;
    for(i = 0 i < ##; i++){ // need to run a loop four times
    x+=1
    }
}
```

Let's consider I am trying to Implement the function that will add one on each subsequent call, like below

```
console.log(add()()().getValue()); // 3
console.log(add().getValue()); // 1
console.log(add()().getValue()); // 2
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You can get close to the answer you want, but you will not get the answer. If you know how many times ahead of time you can do it. If you do not know how many times it will be called, you can not do it.

Comment: So you want the result to depend on the number of parenthesis? That's not possible since you need to return another function to even check if there is a next set, so you can't return a number at the same time.

Comment: The function cannot output another function to be called _as well as_ the answer.

Comment: This should mean that your `add` function will have side effects, meaning that same calls to the `add` function with same input arguments yet does not yield same result/output. Since side effects are expected, the only way I can think of is referencing/mutating a global variable every time `add` is called

Comment: `function add() { var x = 0; function inner() { x += 1; return inner; } return inner; }`…?

Comment: Can you give us the exact problem definition? My guess is that it was more than "add an indefinite number of brackets".

Comment: @djna I want the result to depend on the number of parenthesis.

Comment: Note: The output of your first example is 2, not 3.

Comment: @mkHun It is not possible to do it without knowing the number before hand. You can return a function over and over, but there is no way to know when it is the last one to return the number. You can use .toString() or something else to say it is done.

Comment: The edit changes the nature of the question quite a bit.

Comment: Please don't invalidate existing and accepted answers by rewriting the question.

Comment: @deceze I am not going to change the accepted answer. I got a comment saying the previous edit, that's why I have posted the previous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to `add` must return a function which also has a `getValue` method, and each call to that function must return the same thing. So:

```js
function add() {
    var x = 1;
    
    function inner() {
        x += 1;
        return inner;
    }
    
    inner.getValue = function () {
        return x;
    }
    
    return inner;
}

console.log(add()()().getValue()); // 3
console.log(add().getValue()); // 1
console.log(add()().getValue()); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is they were expecting you to use toString() which is not the greatest way of doing this.

```js
function add(x = 0) {
  function next() {
    return add(x+1);
  }
  next.toString = function () {
    return x;
  };
  return next;
}

console.log("example 1", add()()()());
console.log("example 2", add()()()()()()()()());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to emulate the behavior of generator functions. Here is a snippet that illustrates one way you could do it with a generator.

```
function* adder() {
  let x = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield x + 1;
    x++;
  }
}

const add = adder();

const firstValue = add.next();

const secondValue = add.next();

const thirdValue = add.next().value;
```

Comment: This seems very different from the question.